# when a div is showing do some thing for me and when its hidden stop that , with jquery its possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How i can write if `#menu-drop` `display:block`, add class to `#header`. else remove class from `#header` and follow other codes.

Thanks.

> in CSS file `#menu-drop {display:none};` and follow my jQuery codes it will show with slideDown event.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


jQuery(document).ready(function(){






                    jQuery(document).on("click","#menu-oc",function() {
                        jQuery("#menu-drop").slideToggle("slow");
                    });


                    jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
                        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
                            jQuery("#header").addClass("fixed");
                            jQuery("#header").addClass("goblack");
                        }  else {
                            jQuery("#header").removeClass("fixed");
                            jQuery("#header").removeClass("goblack");
                        }
                    });         



                    jQuery("#introcenter").animate({width: "0"},600,function (){

                    jQuery(".intro").animate({height : "0"},600,function () {
                    jQuery("#main").animate({opacity : "1"},500);
                    });
                    });



});

</script>


<body>
        <div id="header">
            <button id="menu-oc">HELLO</button>
        </div>
        <div id="menu-drop">
            <div id="menu">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu" style="html" />
            </div>
        </div>
<body>
```

Comment: I think you mean javascript not java. Right?

Comment: sorry ? what u mean ?

Comment: you tagged the question with java. correct is JavaScript. I have removed it.

Comment: thanks. did u know the answer?

Comment: no. I am Java not JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your JS code like this -

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 0 && (jQuery('#menu-drop').css('display') == 'none')) {
        jQuery("#header").addClass("fixed");
        jQuery("#header").addClass("goblack");
     }  else {
            jQuery("#header").removeClass("fixed");
            jQuery("#header").removeClass("goblack");
        }
});
```

and then add inline style to your `#menu-drop`

```
display: none;
```

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qxvqmj6/) you will see the `#menu-drop` is displaying and the `#header` is not going `border-color: black;`
now check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qxvqmj6/1/), here you will see I have added an inline style `display: none` to `#menu-drop` and in this case the `#header` is going black!!

Comment: Thank you , i did it with a little change on your help . thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for are jquery [is](http://api.jquery.com/is/)-function and [:visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)-selector.

For example:

```
var $header = $("#header");
if ($("#menu-drop").is(":visible")) {
    $header.addClass("myClass");
}
else 
{
    $header.removeClass("myClass");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer but still not working . the problem is when `#menu-drop` is showing , `#header`after scroll going to black ! i want `#header` just go black after scroll when `#menu-drop` is hidden , and whene its show , scroll dont change any thing or get class white